# How to get the name of a file acting as stdin/stdout?

Tags: io, fortran, stdout, stdin, fortran90

I'm having the following problem. I want to write a program in Fortran90 which I want to be able to call like this:

```
./program.x < main.in > main.out
```

Additionally to "main.out" (whose name I can set when calling the program), secondary outputs have to be written and I wanted them to have a similar name to either "main.in" or "main.out" (they are not actually called "main"); however, when I use:

```
INQUIRE(UNIT=5,NAME=sInputName)
```

The content of sInputName becomes "Stdin" instead of the name of the file. Is there some way to obtain the name of files that are linked to stdin/stdout when the program is called??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately the point of i/o redirection is that you're program doesn't have to know what the input/output files are. On unix based systems you cannot look at the command line arguments as the `< main.in > main.out` are actually processed by the shell which uses these files to set up standard input and output before your program is invoked.

You have to remember that sometimes the standard input and output will not even be files, as they could be a terminal or a pipe. e.g.

```
./generate_input | ./program.x | less
```

So one solution is to redesign your program so that the output file is an explicit argument.

```
./program.x --out=main.out
```

That way your program knows the filename. The cost is that your program is now responsible for openning (and maybe creating) the file.

That said, on linux systems you can actually find yout where your standard file handles are pointing from the special /proc filesystem. There will be symbolic links in place for each file descriptor

```
/proc/<process_id>/fd/0 -> standard_input
/proc/<process_id>/fd/1 -> standard_output
/proc/<process_id>/fd/2 -> standard_error
```

Sorry, I don't know fortran, but a psudeo code way of checking the output file could be:

```
out_name = realLink( "/proc/"+getpid()+"/fd/1" )
if( isNormalFile( out_name ) )
    ...
```

Keep in mind what I said earlier, there is no garauntee this will actually be a normal file. It could be a terminal device, a pipe, a network socket, whatever... Also, I do not know what other operating systems this works on other than redhat/centos linux, so it may not be that portable. More a diagnostic tool.

Comment: +1; I think if you want that level of control, passing the input name to the program and having the program open the file and generate the output file names is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the intrinsic subroutines `get_command` and/or `get_command_argument` can be of help. They were introduced in fortran 2003, and either return the full command line which was used to invoke the program, or the specified argument.