# C Program Standard Input File Name Access

Tags: c, unix, stdin

I was wondering if there is a way to access the name of the standard input file within a C program. I've looked around, and haven't found anything. For example

> ./a.out < file.txt

Is there a way within the C program to print out the name of the file (file.txt)?

Comment: Why would you want to? This is a rather unusual request, and not in the UNIX spirit.

Comment: Generally not. It can be not a file at all - answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602663/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-file-acting-as-stdin-stdout).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, you could accomplish what you want by reading `/proc/[pid]/fd/0` or parsing the out of `lsof -p [pid]`, where `[pid]` is the process ID of your process.

See `proce(5)` and `lsof(8)`.

Answer (score -1):

```
printf("%s", argv[1]);
```

Make sure you have your main set up to accept command line arguments

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

Comment: That would work for `./a.out file.txt`, not `./a.out < file.txt`.

Comment: What if you offset it another string index? such as argv[2]? Would that work