# Check if there is an stdout redirection in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I need to check if my program's output is being redirected; if yes I need to keep and send its by mail.

example:

```
$ myprogram -param1 -param2 -param3 > /home/polly/log.txt
```

`myprogram.sh`:

```
if 'redirection is not empty'; then 
    cat <redirection name> | mailx -s "This is a test email." polly@gmail.com 
fi
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If called as `myprogram > something`, you want to mail the content of `something`?

Comment: Can you please ask a question.

Comment: correct, I want keep someting and send it into body message

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can check if stdout is a terminal. When stdout is redirected or piped it will not be a terminal. You can use the test command with the `-t` option to get this information:

```
if [ -t 1 ] ; then
    # stdout is a terminal
else
    # stdout isn't a terminal
fi
```

From `man test`:

> ```
>   -t FD  file descriptor FD is opened on a terminal
> ```

Comment: [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602663/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-file-acting-as-stdin-stdout)

Comment: @hek2mgl Well, on Linux, you might actually be able to, at least for redirections (not for pipes, though as there is no name), by looking at e.g. `readlink /proc/$$/fd/1` or such...

Comment: @twalberg Yeah, you are right! Cool! Didn't had this in mind.. Thx! :)

Comment: Thanks twalberg, could you explain me how can manage this file (I tryed to copy/cat/type but everytime I receive an error)?

Comment: @JackFrost65 A good program design wouldn't need to know that. Can you explain more general what you are about to do?

Comment: Hi hek2mgl I try to explain. 
I have a procedure that can be submitted from same guys using a different redirection result. I would like to keep and send by mail this redirection.
eg : `myprogram > something` , I want to mail the content of `something`

Comment: Why don't you send the output by mail before outputting it to stdout?

Comment: for two reason, first one all guys (dislocated in different place) that use this script can use a different name of redirection file and second one I need "centraly" to have it.

Comment: @hek2mgl, cannot agree regarding "good program design", it depends. Say such fundamental utils as /bin/ls /usr/bin/diff.
(1) ls gives tabular output to terminal, but gives one per line when output is redirected.
(2) diff may use color output with ANSI escape codes, but does pure black-n-white output by default when redirected. So there are cases when good program design demands to know whether stdout is a terminal